# Does ES6 support the Elvis operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

Does Javascript / ES6 support the [Elvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) operator?

Example:

```
var x = (y==true) ?: 10;
```

Example 2:

```
var debug = true;
debug ?: console.log("Value of x:" + x);
```

Comment: No, there is no Elvis operator but you can use the `||` - `var x = y || 10` for example or `debug || console.log()`

Comment: Apart from what @vlaz said, you could also do one line if statements `if (y === true) 10;` Note that this is not the most popular way of writing if statements cause of lack of readability.

Comment: `||` _is_ the Elvis operator.

Comment: @SalmanA `||` only evaluates if the condition is false. The Elvis operator evaluates if the condition is true. So `&&` is closer to the Elvis operator.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts no. Refer to the definition on wiki which says _that returns its first operand if that operand is considered true, and otherwise evaluates and returns its second operand._ This is what `||` does: `1 || 2 // 1` vs `1 && 2 // 2`.

Comment: The `?:` operator will evaluate the right hand condition if the left hand condition is true. With the `||` operator the condition on the left has to be false for the interpreter to move on and evaluate the condition on the right. *If first condition is false then evaluate second condition. If left condition is true no need to evaluate right condition.* With Elvis operator you want to run the right hand condition if left condition is true. `&&` is closer to Elvis behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, but you can just use || or &&, seems to perform same function.

```
var debug = true;
debug && console.log("debug mode on ");
debug || console.log("debug mode off");
```

Comment: You could mark it as selected also 

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your answer is "No". There is no Elvis operator in javascript. But you can achieve the same behavior in a few different short ways like so:

Using plain ternary operator:

`var x = y ? 10 : null;`

Or using a simple 'if' for just a single output:

`if (debug) console.log("Value of x:", x);`